# Inserting Tumblr "Read More" without breaking Latex Math Type

Tags: tumblr

I am using stackedit.io for editing post on Tumblr. I uploaded the post using the stackedit.io built in system as html code (rather than Markup) as suggested. I noticed that as soon as I edit the post on the Tumblr server and insert a "Read More" in the code, the LATEX math (MathJax) type is broken. Does anyone know how to add a "Read More" snippet without breaking the LATEX math type when I save the post, ie. directly insert the code when editing in stackedit.io?

Thank you,
Ferenc

Answer (score 2):

In StackEdit, you can add this in your document:

```
<!-- more -->
```

It's supposed to work with both Markdown or HTML publishing.